# Need Solution For Below Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    n_CompanyId,
    n_CompanyCode,
    s_CompanyName,
    (select COUNT(em.n_CompanyId) as Total_Employee
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_EmployeeMaster em on (cm.n_CompanyId = em.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId),
    (select COUNT(bm.n_CompanyId) as Total_Branch
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_BranchMaster bm on (cm.n_CompanyId = bm.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId),
    (select COUNT(ca.n_CompanyId) as Total_Employee
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_CompanyApplicationRigths ca on (cm.n_CompanyId = ca.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId),
    d_InsertDate,
    d_ModifiyDate
from 
    tbl_CompanyMaster
group by 
    n_CompanyId
order by 
    n_CompanyId asc
```

When I am trying this got message like

> Column 'tbl_CompanyMaster.n_CompanyCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I am putting this got

```
select 
    n_CompanyId,
    (select COUNT(em.n_CompanyId) as Total_Employee
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_EmployeeMaster em on (cm.n_CompanyId = em.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId),
    (select COUNT(bm.n_CompanyId) as Total_Branch
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_BranchMaster bm on (cm.n_CompanyId = bm.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId),
    (select COUNT(ca.n_CompanyId) as Total_Employee
     from tbl_CompanyMaster cm
     inner join tbl_CompanyApplicationRigths ca on (cm.n_CompanyId = ca.n_CompanyId)
     group by cm.n_CompanyId)
from 
    tbl_CompanyMaster
group by 
    n_CompanyId
order by 
    n_CompanyId asc
```

I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Please format your post/code, otherwise it's too much effort to try and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

is `CompanyApplicationRigths` a typo? should it be `CompanyApplicationRights` ?

```
select 
   n_CompanyId
 , Total_Employee = (
  select count(em.n_CompanyId) 
  from tbl_EmployeeMaster em 
  where cm.n_CompanyId = em.n_CompanyId
    )
 , Total_Branch = (
  select count(bm.n_CompanyId) 
  from tbl_BranchMaster bm 
  where cm.n_CompanyId = bm.n_CompanyId
  )
 , Total_ApplicationRigths = (
  select count(ca.n_CompanyId)
  from tbl_CompanyApplicationRigths ca 
  where  cm.n_CompanyId = ca.n_CompanyId)
  )
from tbl_CompanyMaster as cm
group by n_CompanyId
order by n_CompanyId asc
```

can also be written as:

```
select
    n_CompanyId
  , Total_Employee = count(em.*)
  , Total_Branch =  count(bm.*)
  , Total_ApplicationRigths = count(ca.*)
from tbl_CompanyMaster as cm
  left join tbl_EmployeeMaster em 
    on cm.n_CompanyId = em.n_CompanyId
  left join tbl_BranchMaster bm 
    on cm.n_CompanyId = bm.n_CompanyId
  left join tbl_CompanyApplicationRigths ca 
    on cm.n_CompanyId = ca.n_CompanyId
group by n_CompanyId
order by n_CompanyId asc
```